# how to get keys and its values which are arrays from a document field using mongodb query

Tags: mongodb

I have a below json which is inserted into the mongodb.

```
{
   "_id":"1001",
   "post":{
      "country_name":"India",
      "state_name":"Maharashtra",
      "city_name":"Mumbai",
      "duration":"10",

      "country":[
         {
            "name":"india"   
         }
      ],
      "site":[
         {
            "site_no":"101",
            "code":"Taj",
            "name":"santacruz"
         }
      ]
   },
   "post_id":"abcd123"
}
```

With that document, I need 2 different results.

1. To get only the key - value pairs from "post" which are non arrays. ie.

   ```
    "post":{
     "country_name":"India",
     "state_name":"Maharashtra",
     "city_name":"Mumbai",
     "duration":"10"
    }
   ```
2. To get only arrays from "post". i.e.,

   ```
   "post":{          
     "country":[
        {
           "name":"india"   
        }
     ],
     "site":[
        {
           "site_no":"101",
           "code":"Taj",
           "name":"santacruz"
        }
     ]
   }
   ```

Is there any ways to achieve the above scenarios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you want to loop all the fields in `post` and retrieve them only if they are arrays or not

```
    db.<yourcollectionname>.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            postFields: { $objectToArray: "$post" } // This will transform post in an array of object { k: nameOfTheField, v: valueOfTheField }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$postFields" // This will split the array in separate documents
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$postFields" } // This is just transforming from { postFields: { k , v } } to { k, v }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            v: { $not: { $type: "array" } } // We are filtering for fields that are not array here
        }
    }
])
```

This is the output with the aggregation above:

```
{ "k" : "country_name", "v" : "India" }
{ "k" : "state_name", "v" : "Maharashtra" }
{ "k" : "city_name", "v" : "Mumbai" }
{ "k" : "duration", "v" : "10" }
```

If you want to obtain the array type fields, just remove the `$not` operator from the last `$match` stage:

```
{
    $match: {
            v: {  $type: "array" } // We are filtering for fields that are only array
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{ "k" : "country", "v" : [ { "name" : "india" } ] }
{ "k" : "site", "v" : [ { "site_no" : "101", "code" : "Taj", "name" : "santacruz" } ] }
```

This aggregation will work for all the documents, if you want to execute for just one document, simply add a `$match` stage at the start of the aggregation:

```
{
    $match: { _id: "1001" } // The id of your document
}
```

Comment: that worked, how can we run this same query using "Mongo Java driver" or "Jongo"

Comment: @Jerin [this](https://github.com/ihr/jongo-by-example/blob/master/src/test/java/org/ingini/mongodb/jongo/example/aggregation/TestAggregationFramework.java) seems to be a working example on how to run an aggregation in jongo

Comment: how to write it in java. Can you please help me to complete the below version.
AggregateIterable<Document> testDoc = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
                        Aggregates.match(Filters.eq("_id", "1001")),
                        Aggregates.project(new Document("_id", 0)
                                .append("fields", Filters.eq("$objectToArray", "$post"))),
                        Aggregates.unwind("$fields"),
                        Aggregates.replaceRoot(new Document("newRoot", "$fields")),
                        Aggregates.match()
                ));

Comment: @Jerin can't you just insert aggregation stages as strings like [this](https://jongo.org/#querying) (See aggregation Framework example)?

Comment: with Jongo I can, but I'm trying with mongo driver, since I can't use jongo in my project.